# How do I browse /tmp in Finder?

Tags: finder

I can use the command line to :-

```
cd /tmp
ls -al
```

What is the equivalent to do so in finder?
I can't seems find a way to browse to that folder using finder,
(my intention is to view images which I created in /tmp)

Or is there any image browser tools can do the same?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the menu Go -> Go to folder and enter the path of the folder you wish to see in the resulting dialog.

You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to summon the dialog.

Comment: Too good to be true :)

Comment: Glad I could help! =)

Comment: This only works that nice when you're using the **system language** English. It does not work in German. Here is why: In the **terminal** all directories have English names no matter what the system settings. However, using the **go to folder** option you need to use system language directory names. ``~/Bilder`` instead of ``~/Pictures``. That can get really confusing. Can I change that? I don't know all the German directory names...

Comment: If you do this a lot, you might want to make a link from /tmp to somewhere more convenient , i.e. "ln -s /tmp ~/Desktop/tmp" so you don't have to use Go menu every time.

Comment: yet, there are people who claim how "intuitive" mac is ... thank you

Answer (score 22):

Writing `open /tmp` in Terminal will open the `/tmp` folder in Finder.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way I just find out is to use browser (chrome, firefox),
and in the URL bar :-

```
file:///tmp/
```

This work like apache index directory,
is usable, but is far from ideal