# Browse to /tmp in file dialog

Tags: macos

How can I browse to `/tmp` to select a file in a file dialog window, such as the one Chrome uses to select an attachment? I am aware of how to browse to other folders as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32377/how-do-i-browse-tmp-in-finder). I could probably drag and drop, but I would prefer to simply select the file from a list in the appropriate folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In file dialogs you can press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd> (just like in Finder) to enter the path to any folder/directory you want to open.